# Duda con PHP PDO

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo

ando practicando un poco con php y empece hace nada a usar PDO, el problema es que en uno de mis ejercicios he intentado hacer que mi codigo me imprima el numero 33 y no se por que no logro conseguirlo, me aparece una especie de error asi Ha ocurrido un error de base de datos SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.
he movido varias cosas pero no logro solucionarlo, me crea las dos tablas la uno y la dos pero luego de eso no funciona el resto, algun consejo por favor

```
<?php 
$pdo=null;
try {
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mi_practica;", 'miusuario', 'Miclave');
    $pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $pdo->exec( "CREATE TABLE tabla_uno (valor INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL)ENGINE=INNODB" );
    $pdo->exec ("CREATE TABLE tabla_dos (valor INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL)ENGINE=MYISAM");

    $statement_insert_uno=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla_uno(valor) VALUES(val)");
    $statement_insert_dos=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla_dos(valor) VALUES(?)");

    $pdo->begintransaction();
    $statement_insert_uno->execute ([':val'=> 4]);
    $statement_insert_uno->execute([':?val'=> 5]);
    $statement_insert_uno->execute([':val'=> 6]);
    $pdo->commit();

    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $statement_insert_dos->execute([100]);
    $statement_insert_dos->execute([33]);
    $pdo->rollback () ;

    $pdo->beginTransaction () ;
    $statement_insert_dos->execute([15]);
    $statement_insert_dos->execute([3]);
    pdo->commit();

    $suma_resultado_uno=0;
    $statement_resultados_uno=$pdo->query("SELECT SUM(valor) AS suma FROM tabla_uno");
    $datos_resultados_uno=$statement_resultados_uno->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    $suma_resultado_uno=$datos_resultados_uno['suma'];

    $suma_resultado_dos=0;
    $statement_resultados_dos=$pdo->query("SELECT FROM tabla_dos");
    while ($datos_resultados_dos=$statement_resultados_dos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $suma_resultado_dos+=$datos_resultados_dos['valor'];
    }
    echo $suma_resultado_uno+$suma_resultado_dos;

}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error de base de datos ".$e->getMessage();
    if($pdo->inTransaction()){
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Hay varios errores, todos tipográficos que sugieren el cierre de la pregunta. Línea 10 olvidaste los `:` en `... VALUES(:val)`. Línea 15 hay un `?` de más, es `[':val'=> 5]`. Línea 27, falta el signo de `$` en el objeto PDO: `$pdo->commit();`. Línea 31, está incorrecto el uso de PDO::FETCH_BOUND, si no lo conoces, usa `FETCH::ASSOC`. Línea 35, se te olvidó la columna en la consulta, `SELECT valor FROM ...`.

Comment: @aeportugal no me dejaste nada XD ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 jeje es que lo traté de reproducir en mi entorno hasta que corriera, así que ahí están todos los problemas. Quizás, algo basado en opiniones, es que al menos en mi caso no me gusta esconder errores con bloques try/catch, a lo mucho para la conexión porque así lo recomiendan, pero veo devs que meten grandes bloques de código, incluso funciones enteras dentro de estas clausulas, para mi es mala práctica, pero bueno. Saludos ;)

Comment: En realidad se usan para capturar cualquier error y mostrarlo en mi caso; en devs muestro los error es por pantalla asi: https://i.imgur.com/7dj1tTp.png  y en produccion muevo todo a un log.

Comment: en symfonyu uso dd() etc ... XD

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, esto de tratar de aprender algo por tu cuneta es dificil jajaja, pero me ayudaron mucjo